# How to display LINQ Lambda Expression to a textbox

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am kind of new to Lambda Expressions, I have tried to work out a simple solution to the following task I have set myself.
A customer has a collection of cars. Use LINQ to get a total number of cars he has.
Code below, not sure if this is correct? My second question is how do you display the `TotalNumberCars` to a textbox?

```
using (Entities dbcontext = new Entities())
{
    var ListByOwner = from c in dbcontext.Owners
                      where c.OwnerID == OwnerID
                      group c by c.Cars into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Owner = g.Key,
                          TotalNumberCars = g.Sum(x => x.Cars)
                      };

    lblTotalCars.Text = ListByOwner.ToList();
}
```

Comment: ListByOwner.Count()

Comment: Much homework, heh?

Comment: One question at a time, please. Also, _"not sure if this is correct?"_ isn't a question. If you can't tell whether it's correct, there's no way we could. You know it's correct by running the code and seeing if it does what you want. If it does what you want, it's correct. If it doesn't, it's not. It's unclear in what way you want to display `TotalNumberCars`; you will presumably have multiple instances of that value...do you want the sum of that value? Just one of the instances? Something else? This question is unclear, too broad, _and_ missing a good [mcve] that would help us understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your entity data model is structured, but I would do it like this:

```
using (var dbContext = new Entities())
{
    var numberOfCars = dbContext.Cars.Count(c => c.OwnerId == OwnderId);
    lblTotalCars.Text = numberOfCars.ToString();
}
```

If there's no c.OwnerId then maybe you can access it by typing c.Owner.OwnerId.

Answer (score 1):

`ListByOwner.ToList()` is an array (generic list) of your new items from your `Select` projection. Each item is a dynamic entity with two properties of `Owner` and `TotalNumberCars`. You need to index or foreach into the list, extract what is needed into a string and that can be your text.

Such as `lblTotalCars.Text = ListByOwner[0].Owner;` will display the first item's owner.

Take this and fill in what you need.

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
lblTotalCars.Text = ListByOwner.ToList().sum(c=>c.TotalNumberCars).ToString();
```